# Performance on iOS WebView, Safari Inspector: What is the "Other" category causing so much jank?

Tags: performance, mobile-safari, safari-web-inspector, ios-web-app

I am doing some performance work on my iOS Cordova app. I have an iPhone 14 Pro, and I'm testing a very basic animation in my app where, from the Settings page of my app, I tap a saved payment method, which animates to reveal a "gutter" with a button to remove the payment method. So basically, there is just one small rectangle in the page animating to the left when the gutter opens:

[image: rm payment method]

I'm using a CSS transition to animate the transform property (using translateX).

When I open my cordova webview in Safari Inspector and profile the animation, on the Frames tab I see lots of frames that don't make the 60fps cut, but in those cases, the time is being consumed in the "Other" category (as opposed to Layout, Paint, etc). So, what is Other? What can I possibly do to decrease the time spent in Other?

[image: safari profile]